# How to predict state vector of a quantum circuit in IBM qiskit

Tags: qiskit, hadamard, ibm-quantum-devices, linear-algebra

How to Predict the state vector output of the following quantum circuit?

```
qc= QuantumCircuit(3)

qc.h(0)

qc.cx([0,0],[1,2])

backend_sv = BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator') 

job = execute(qc, backend_sv,shots=1024)

result = job.result()

sv_ev = result.get_statevector(qc)
```

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Please edit your question to indicate under what context this is being asked. What language is this, etc.

Comment: It's a IBM qiskit code and language is python.